# If a reverse shell target is an administrator does the attacker have admin?

Tags: reverse-shell

If a reverse shell target is an administrator does the attacker have admin?
I've been trying to find the answer to this but can only find general information on how they connect to a target and not whether they maintain admin.

Comment: Do you mean "If an admin runs the reverse shell, does the shell run as admin?"

Answer (score 4):

A reverse shell is a normal program. It runs as the user it is executed from. E.g. if you convince a php application to execute a reverse shell, you may get the same user access as the webserver it is running on such as `www-data`.

With the same logic, if you convince a human user logged with administrator/root rights to run a reverse shell connecting back to your machine then yes, it will allow you to execute the administrator/root commands.